# Print a stack trace to stdout on errors in Django while using IIS

Tags: python, ajax, django, iis, google-chrome-devtools

I have my Django Web application already mounted in IIS version 10 and I am able to see some views but I am unable to see other views working because I am getting the following error in my browser's console when I do my AJAX request:

```
GET http://10.51.112.24:89/statistics/chart-data3 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am searching for a snippet of a logging configuration to get Django or IIS to just output a stack trace when it encounters an error during a request. This code is specifically for local debugging and mainly when I do AJAX GET/POST requests.

So far, I have enabled the following logging configurations in my settings.py file but they are not enough to trace down this error:

```
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

Any tool or code snippet that can help me to troubleshoot better this problem besides the web browser console from Chrome is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped me to better troubleshoot my Ajax request problem:

This code goes into the ajax request, results are displayed in the console web browser.

```
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
 }
```